# How to relate probability and frequency of occurrence of an event

Tags: probability

I am not in the field but I need some help with "counting" the occurrence of an event as related to the probability it may occur.

Let me explain.
I have a group of 74 people: 42 are Spanish, 16 are Russian and 16 are Japanese.
John is Russian and is a member of this group. He reported he is friend with 9 Spanish, 2 Russian and 2 Japanese.

How do I "calculate" the number of friends he has from each group taking into account the probability of having a friend of that group? Should I consider also that he himself is Russian when calculating probability?

I suppose his friendship with the Russian (or the Japanese) people should "weight" more, since there is less probability that it occurs (22%, compared to the probability of being friend with Spanish which is 56%)...

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear what you are asking. You already know how many friends John has of each nationality. What is there to "calculate"? Are you looking for how the actual number corresponds to the expected value? The expected value would be John has 13 friends, so you would expect $\dfrac{42}{73}$ of them to be Spanish, $\dfrac{15}{73}$ of them to be Russian, and $\dfrac{16}{73}$ of them to be Japanese (you exclude John himself, unless it is possible for John to be friends with himself).

Assuming each member of the group has an equal chance to become friends with John (if John is learning Spanish, and looking for Spanish friends to practice with, that changes the odds, but we are ignoring possibilities like that), the expected numbers of friends would be:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{nationality} & \text{number} \\ \hline \text{Spanish} & 7.5 \\ \text{Russian} & 2.7 \\ \text{Japanese} & 2.8\end{array}$$